# Python MATTER protocol device

Tags: python

Is there a python script that simulates a MATTER protocol device and a python script that can receive it.

i have looked in
https://github.com/project-chip/connectedhomeip  but couldnt find any.

are there any python lib for MATTER protocol?

Comment: Hello @Rinel, did you find anything in the mean time ?

Answer (score 2):

There is a Python SDK which provides bindings to some C/C++ SDK functionality.

You can find a good example under the [examples/lighting-app/python](https://github.com/project-chip/connectedhomeip/tree/master/examples/lighting-app/python) directory.

Here is a very simple script to handle on/off commands in Python:

```py
from chip.server import (
    GetLibraryHandle,
    PostAttributeChangeCallback,
)

CLUSTER_ONOFF = 6
ATTR_ONOFF = 0


@PostAttributeChangeCallback
def attributeChangeCallback(endpoint: int, clusterId: int, attributeId: int, xx_type: int, size: int, value: bytes):
    if endpoint == 1:
        if clusterId == CLUSTER_ONOFF and attributeId == ATTR_ONOFF:
            if value and value[0] == 1:
                print(">>> on <<<")
            else:
                print(">>> off <<<")


chipLib = GetLibraryHandle(attributeChangeCallback)

input('Press any key to exit')
```

The endpoint, cluster, and attribute IDs are based on the matter definitions. The sources and pre-compiled definitions are under [examples/lighting-app/lighting-common](https://github.com/project-chip/connectedhomeip/tree/master/examples/lighting-app/lighting-common) and [zzz_generated/lighting-app/zap-generated](https://github.com/project-chip/connectedhomeip/blob/master/zzz_generated/lighting-app/zap-generated) respectively.